# Am using realloc function here two times in a row and it doesn't seem to work , I use it once and it works completely fine can someone tell me why?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc, calloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *ptr;
int n;

int main()
{
    ptr = (char *)calloc(n, sizeof(char));
    // First ID
    printf("Enter the length of your employ ID\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &ptr[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", ptr[i]);
    }
    // Second ID
    printf("Enter the size of new ID\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    ptr = (char *)realloc(ptr, n * sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%c", &ptr[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("%c", ptr[i]);
    }

    // Third ID

    printf("Enter the size of new ID\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
```

ptr = (char *)realloc(ptr, n * sizeof(char));

```
for (int i =0; i <=n; i++)
{
    scanf("%c", &ptr[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    printf("%c", ptr[i]);
}

return 0;
```

}

I tried to Get Ids of three people but the program doesnt work and after taking the input once it just exits : ( . It works fine when I use realloc once but not twice can someone explain why ?
[it takes the input and then exits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hLAV.png)

Comment: Look at `main`.  The first thing it does is call `calloc`, allocating `n` elements.  But `n` hasn't been set yet.  Since it's a global, it's implicitly initialized to `0`.  So you're calling `calloc` with a size of `0`.  Then you set `n` to the desired value.   Then you try to access `n` elements of the array, even though they haven't been allocated.  Did it occur to you to read the value of `n` *before* trying to use it to allocate memory?  Think about what you're doing.

Comment: Also, if you're allocating `n` elements, the valid indices range from `0` to `n-1`, inclusive.  So why are all of your loops running from `0` through `n`, i.e. why are they trying to access `n+1` elements?  Change your loops tests to `i < n`, not `i <= n`.  Again, think about what you're doing.  There are lots of bugs here.

Comment: So you are saying the sequence of when i write scanf matters ?

Comment: Everything in C is done sequentially.  How could the sequence possibly not matter?  Try to understand that if you have one statement followed by another, the first statement is executed first, then the second statement is executed.  Read a C tutorial before trying to use `malloc` and friends.

Comment: I tried i<n but doesnt print all the elements idk why i<=n works just fine

Comment: Okay now I understand for some reason I thought sequence didn't matter thanks for telling me

Comment: It doesn't work "just fine".  You're masking one bug with another.  You seem to be saying "I like to index past the end of my arrays, because it seems to work fine".

Comment: OKay i wont use i<=n but i fixed the sequence but still there is a problem when i try to reallocate the size second time

Comment: Nm It works you were right sequence was the problem but, i<n still doesnt work , for eg. i set the size to 4 and give input as 1234 and the it only prints 123 , but if I use i<=n the 1234 is printed as 1234 . Am still trying to understand why is it that way

Comment: Ok, I know why `< n` doesn't seem to work.  The problem is the first character your're reading is the newline from the previous string (where you entered the length of the ID).  So if you enter `1234` for the ID, what you're getting is `\n`, `1`, `2`, `3`.  The `<= n` causes it to read a fifth character, `4`, writing past the bounds of your array.  You can fix it by changing `scanf("%c", ...)` to `scanf(" %c", ...)`.  I.e. add a space before `%c`.  That will make it skip white space (i.e. the newline).

Comment: That's Perfect, Thank you so much , I actually came across the scanf problem a while ago and saw the explaination but I just completely forgot . Now the code works  with i<n : ) .

Comment: Note that using `" %c"` in your loop will cause it to skip white space before *all* characters in the ID.  So things like `1 234` would be accepted.  If you don't want that, you could only include the space when reading the first character of the ID.  Alternatively, you could read an entire line, then extract the ID from that.

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
int n;
```

declares `n` at file scope. Objects declared at file scope have static storage duration and are always initialised. In the absence of an explicit initialization, they are implicitly initialised to zero.

---

From the C standard C11 6.7.9/10:

> "... If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not
> initialized explicitly, then:
>
> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
> unsigned) zero;"

---

### Accessing out of bounds memory:

Then:

```
ptr = (char *)calloc(n, sizeof(char));
```

allocates memory for 0 objects.

---

> The calloc() function allocates memory for an array of nmemb elements
> of size bytes each and returns a pointer to the allocated memory. The
> memory is set to zero. If nmemb or size is 0, then calloc() returns
> either NULL, or a unique pointer value that can later be successfully
> passed to free().

> On error, these functions return NULL. NULL may also be returned by a
> successful call to malloc() with a size of zero, or by a successful
> call to calloc() with nmemb or size equal to zero.

But you didn't check the return value of `calloc`.

---

Then, this statement:

```
scanf("%c", &ptr[i]);
```

tries to access memory that wasn't allocated, and thus invokes undefined Behaviour.

---

### Off by one error:

You have allocated space for `n` elements, but the condition:

```
i <= n
```

tries to access `n + 1` elements, which is memory out of bounds, memory you haven't allocated, memory that doesn't belong to you, and is thus undefined behaviour. (But that's irrelevant since you didn't allocate anything in the first place).

---

Regarding `realloc`:

> The realloc() function returns a pointer to the newly allocated
> memory, which is suitably aligned for any kind of variable and may be
> different from ptr, or NULL if the request fails. If size was equal to
> 0, either NULL or a pointer suitable to be passed to free() is
> returned. If realloc() fails the original block is left untouched; it
> is not freed or moved.

Which means that if it fails and returns `NULL`, then `ptr` gets initialised with `NULL` and you lose all access to the original memory.

One solution is to use another pointer:

```
char *new = realloc(ptr, size);
if (!new) { /* if realloc failed */
   /* deal with it however you wish */
}

/* If we got here, it means that we weren't bounded */
ptr = new;. /* Now ptr points to the new memory, if it didn't already */
new = 0;    /* This avoids a dangling pointer */ 


/* some code relevant to ptr here */
free(ptr);  /* For every allocation, there must be a call to free */
```

*Side note:* You shouldn't cast the result of `malloc` and family. It's redundant and may hide a bug. The `void *` returned by these functions is automatically promoted to the correct type.

---

### Trailing newline:

```
scanf("%d", &n);
```

leaves a newline in the input buffer, which automatically gets read by subsequent calls to scanf, and you might never be prompted for input.

Instead of:

```
scanf("%c");
```

Use `" %c"` with a leading blank to skip optional white space:

```
scanf(" %c");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please note that you're using:

```
ptr = (char *)calloc(n, sizeof(char));
```

when `n` isn't explicitly initialized in file scope so it is automatically initialized to 0. So basically you overwrite a buffer of size 0 in:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
{
    scanf("%c", &ptr[i]);
}
```

while exceeding the size allocated with `i <= n` which sould be `i < n`, that is probably why.

Second, you must free your memory allocation at the end using `free` and check allocation's success.

Third, when using strings, you might want to use `scanf` using `%s`, unless you have a specific reason.

A more clear and less error prone implementation may be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        int size, times, i;
        char *ptr;

        printf("Enter the number of IDs to enter\n");
        scanf("%d", &times);

        for (i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
                printf("Enter the size of new ID\n");
                scanf("%d", &size);
                if (size < 0) {
                        printf("Entered value is negative\n");
                        return size; // or any other error
                }

                // note the '+ 1' so we have a NULL terminating string
                ptr = (char *)calloc(size + 1, sizeof(char));
                if (ptr == NULL) {
                        printf("Error allocating ptr\n");
                        return -1; // or any other error
                }

                printf("Enter your ID\n");
                scanf("%s", ptr);

                printf("Your ID is: %s\n", ptr);
                free(ptr);
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Hopefully I answered everything and didn't miss a thing (: